# Game sprites with Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, cs6, games, sprite

I redesigned this sprite sheet, based on Mega Man X in falcon armor. I designed it with Illustrator CS6 but when I exported it as a `.png` file and then imported it to PS CS6, I found that the character shook his whole body like crazy, while my aim was just breathing animation (head, chest and arms). I have tried a lot of ways and looked up on google but still didn't know how to solve it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello again (I'm the guy from StackOverflow).

I don't really understand the problem, but looking at your image I do notice something odd.

First of all, your sprite sheet has 6 frames and is 720 pixels wide. Normally, this would mean that each frame should be 720 / 6 = 120 pixels wide.

This is how each frame should be limited:

[image]

All rectangles there are equivalent. Now let's overlap your sprite sheet with my template:

[image]

There is a clear problem here. Your sprites are not evenly distributed. You can see his leg overflowing to other frames.

Instead, it should be kinda like this:

[image]

I don't know what are you doing to test the sprite sheet, but try replacing it with this one (I did it quickly so there's probably a subtle mistake somewhere, but I think that at least the shake will be less noticeable and will put you in the right path to fix it):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot bro !!!!!!!! I tried to find informations about u to keep in touch with you. I hope that we xcan be friends. @Omega

Comment: @ZGMF-X10A: It worked? Click the green check to accept my answer :P. And if you need to contact me you can... uh, actually I'm not sure how. I also do game development.